# If Earth starts moving when attracted by an object, where does the energy come from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work

Suppose a body(very big but not bigger than Earth) moves against gravitational force of Earth. The force will do negative work on the body decreasing its kinetic energy. The decreasing energy is converted to potential energy. Now as gravitational force is mutual and also due to Newton's third law of motion, the body will exert force equal to its weight on Earth and will do positive work on it. The Earth,though very big, will accelerate slightly towards the body. As it is accelerating , kinetic energy of it is increasing. According to Law of Conservation of energy, the increasing kinetic energy is not created; it must be transferred to this form from other. So, from where does the Earth get this increasing kinetic energy??? Please help.

[ I think the increasing kinetic energy of the Earth comes from the potential energy of the body-Earth system. Thus it is the **kinetic energy lost by the body when ascending upwards against the gravitational force** cum the **potential energy** that supplies the kinetic energy of the accelerating Earth and energy is conserved hence. Am I right? If not, why??]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose a body(very big but not bigger than Earth) moves against gravitational force of Earth.

Let us take a real situation: a large rocket is fired *straight up*. It takes  kinetic energy from the chemical explosions; from momentum conservation part of the available energy from the explosion moves the earth in the opposite direction.

The gravitational force will slow down the rocket, but viewed in the center of mass system of the two bodies both the earth and the rocket will be slowing down because of their mutual attraction.

> The force will do negative work on the body decreasing its kinetic energy.

OK

> The decreasing energy is converted to potential energy.

Yes.

> Now as gravitational force is mutual and also due to Newton's third law of motion, the body will exert force equal to its weight on Earth and will do positive work on it.
>
> The Earth,though very big, will accelerate slightly towards the body.

Hmm, no. The earth and rocket *initially* are accelerating *away* from each other due to the explosion, and then will both start decelerating until the zero momentum is reached for both, and the maximum of potential energy i.e. maximum separation, *then* they will  accelerate towards each other, the rocket will fall .

> As it is accelerating , kinetic energy of it is increasing.
>
> According to Law of Conservation of energy, the increasing kinetic energy is not created; it must be transferred to this form from other. So, from where does the Earth get this increasing kinetic energy??? Please help.

From the original explosion. The original explosion released energy divided between earth and rocket,  then because of the dynamics it turned into potential energy at the peak of the trajectory,  and then because of the unimpeded attraction, turned again into kinetic energy  as the earth and rocket accelerate towards each other and meet with a bang.

Edit after comment:

Note that nothing can move against the gravitational pull of each other, as gravitation is always attractive, unless outside energy is provided .

Let us take the hypothetical case that two objects, far away from other gravitational fields are at a distance r, at rest with each other by coincidence of the dynamics of the creation of the cosmos. Then it is true that due to their gravitational attraction their potential energy will turn into kinetic energy as they fall at each other. The energy originally to be found at this position at rest with each other was provided by the original creation of these two objects, i.e. the [Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) energies in the BB model.

Comment: Sir, if I take a tomato in place of the rocket? When a tomato is thrown upwards,what will happen then? There is no explosion now!

Comment: exactly the same thing, you provide the energy with the impulse of the throw , taken from the breaking of chemical bonds in the matter that makes you up, and ultimately from the heat of sun that makes things grow that you eat and have available energy. Again, you-and-the-earth initially accelerate downwards and the tomato upwards: from momentum conservation the available energy is shared. (it is the huge mass of the earth that is confusing you, very little motion is needed to give the same momentum as to the tomato).

Comment: Great answer! When the tomato is thrown up, it accelerates momentarily and gains KE from the energy of the thrower. By conservation of momentum & Newton's third law, the thrower-&-earth will accelerate momentarily using the internal energy of the thrower. But due to mutual gravitation, they decelerate & ultimately come to a halt. Their KE thus is converted to PE . When they accelerate towards each other, their PE is converted tn PE. Thus it is all the energy of the thrower. Energy and momentum thus are conserved,right?

Comment: yes, that is a correct summary

Comment: have you checked http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force . the answers you have got are on those lines.

Comment: My thinking: To accelerate the rocket at first, huge force much greater than gravitation is needed,which is gained from the explosion. But if there were no force after that, they will decelerate and then will accelerate towards each other like the tomato....

Comment: ...So to move with acceleration, the huge force should be imparted continuously so that part of it works against the earth's gravity which will be stored as PE & the rest force will accelerate it to the escape velocity...

Comment: i said they will bang on each other, earth and rocket, after the zero momentum is reached and the energy is fully potential, they will fall on each other.

Comment: First I apologise to contact you from this thread after over a year. But if you help me clearing some problem, I would be grateful. Let a spring be fixed at one end & a block is attached at the other end(vertical configuration under gravity). The block would provide a force $mg$ on the spring & it would get stretched till the restoring force balances $mg$. However, restoring force is not the reactive force due to third law; as the block imparts $mg$ on the spring downward, spring must provide a restoring force on the block upward. Now , my question is: does the block move up? ...

Comment: ...why I'm telling that restoring force is not the reactive force, check [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/can-hookes-law-go-along-with-newtons-3rd-law-how-is-momentum-conserved-in-ca). So, when the spring provides the reactive  force, why doesn't the block upward then? I know I am really confusing something. Can you please clear away my confusion?? BTW, I have to consider the wall also to which the spring is attached in order to consider the conservation of momentum. Thanks in advance & again pardon for bothering you:)

Comment: If I have a weight hanging from a spring I have a harmonic oscillator to start with, weight will be oscillating until dissipation stops the oscillations because it eats up the energy available: heat of the spring . So the weight will come at rest,the spring stretched up to a certain point.  This stretching  is used in old fashioned  spring weight measurements except the spring is chosen with appropriate coefficients to stop the oscillation. ( high dissipation )

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the work made by the gravitational force of the big object that attracts the Earth. I updated my answer to a previous question from you. But remember that the description in terms of conservation of energy and the use of potential energies is an alternative description (usually simpler) than that using all the forces involved (specially reactive forces from the 3rd law). You can switch back and forth between the two descriptions, but you will become confused if you try to use both simultaneously, as this was not the original intention when developing the new formalism of conservative forces and field potentials.

Comment: So,sir is my intuition right?

Comment: Your intuition is right, but try not to mix both description together. You should either use the forces description (including the third law) or the potential energy description, which usually ignores it (because it is already implicitly included as potentials)

Comment: Just a comment: the rocket example was not the best one, because it has the additional complication that the force that pushes the rocket up also pushes the earth down. So, see Anas's answer that applies to that case. My example was for a simplified case where the force that moves the mass do not interact with the earth (for instance, if the mass is charged and there is an electric force outside earth that attracts the charged mass but do not interact with the  Earth.